# How to evaluate the integral: $I=\int_0^3\frac{x\sqrt{x+1}dx}{x^2+x+1}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluating this integral: $I=\int_0^3\frac{x\sqrt{x+1}dx}{x^2+x+1}$

I've tried:

Set : $\sqrt{x+1}=t\mapsto dx=2t\,dt \Longrightarrow I=2\int_1^2\frac{t^4-t^2}{t^4-t^2+1}dt=2\int_1^2(1-\frac{1}{t^4-t^2+1})dt$

And then, I set $(t^2-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan v$ ... But I can't continue to solve this integral...

Comment: Now are you sure that this integral has an anti derivative?

Comment: @imranfat: Rational functions always have an antiderivative expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. Yes, that is true, but see my comment below to Lab

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle t^4-t^2+1=(t^2+1)^2-3t^2=(t^2+\sqrt3t+1)(t^2-\sqrt3t+1)$

$$\frac1{t^4-t^2+1}=\frac1{2\sqrt3t}\left(\frac1{t^2-\sqrt3t+1}-\frac1{t^2+\sqrt3t+1}\right)$$

Using [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) ,

$$t^2-\sqrt3t+1=\frac{4t^2-4\sqrt3t+4}4=\frac{(2t-\sqrt3)^2+1}4$$

So set, $2t-\sqrt3=\tan\phi$ etc.

Comment: Oh... $(t^2+1)^2-t^2=t^4+t^2+1$?? Not $t^4-t^2+1$

Comment: @abcdxyz, have you noticed the edited version?

Comment: Yep . I've seen. Thank you very much. That's right :D But Can you help me by onther way?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Cool, because when I typed this integral in Wolfram, it gave some terms with $i$ in it, leading me to suggest that it doesn't have an elementary anti derivative. Now I do have some more examples of integrals that wolfram can't do whereas there is an elementary answer, but here I got stumped anyway...

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
I &\equiv \int_{0}^{3}{x\root{x + 1}\,dx \over x^{2} + x + 1}
=\int_{0}^{3}x\root{x + 1}\,
\pars{{1 \over x + 1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2} - {1 \over x + 1/2 + \root{3}\ic/2}}\,
{1 \over \root{3}\ic}\,dx
\\[3mm]&={2\root{3} \over 3}\Im\int_{0}^{3}
{x\ \overbrace{\root{x + 1}}^{\ds{\equiv\ t}} \over x + 1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}\,\dd x
={2\root{3} \over 3}\Im\int_{1}^{2}
{\pars{t^{2} - 1}t \over \pars{t^{2} - 1} + 1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}\,2t\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&={4\root{3} \over 3}\Im\int_{1}^{2}
{\pars{t^{2} - 1}t^{2} \over t^{2} + z}\,\dd t
\qquad\mbox{where}\qquad
z \equiv -\,\half - {\root{3} \over 2}\,\ic =\expo{4\pi\ic/3}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\pars{1}
\end{align}
$z$ is a root of $z^{2} + z + 1 = 0$.

> \begin{align}
> I &={4\root{3} \over 3}\Im\int_{0}^{2}
> {\bracks{\pars{t^{2} + z} - \pars{z + 1}}\bracks{\pars{t^{2} + z} - z}
> \over t^{2} + z}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&={4\root{3} \over 3}\Im\int_{0}^{2}
> {\pars{t^{2} + z}^{2} - \pars{2z + 1}\pars{t^{2} + z}
>  +\ \overbrace{z\pars{z + 1}}^{\ds{=\ - 1}} \over t^{2} + z}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&={4\root{3} \over 3}\Im\int_{0}^{2}
> \bracks{\pars{t^{2} + z} - \pars{2z + 1} - {1 \over t^{2} + z}}\,\dd t
> ={4\root{3} \over 3}\pars{{\root{3} \over 2}
>                           - \Im\int_{0}^{2}{\dd t \over t^{2} + z}}
> \\[3mm]&=2 - {4\root{3} \over 3}\,
> \Im\pars{\expo{-2\pi\ic/3}\int_{0}^{2\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}}
> \end{align}

$$
\mbox{Evaluate the right hand side}:\quad
I=2 - {4\root{3} \over 3}\,
\Im\bracks{\expo{-2\pi\ic/3}\arctan\pars{2\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}}
$$